# Candy Box 2 When I am in quests I am constantly walking forward, is this normal?

Tags: candy-box-2

I have no idea if this is normal but when I am in quests like fighting the nougat monster, I can not stand still. I am constantly walking forward towards the monster. This makes beating the nougat monster very hard. Please tell me if this is normal or what I do to stop walking forward.

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is normal. If you don't want to walk forward, you will need to obtain the [Boots of Introspection](http://candybox2.gamepedia.com/Boots_of_Introspection).

Those can be obtained by defeating yourself.

To defeat yourself, you need to make an [X-Potion](http://candybox2.gamepedia.com/X_Potion) and then use it in a quest. The only way to defeat yourself, is if you are wearing the Octopus King's Crown (not enchanted).

To make an X-Potion

1. Put a candy in your cauldron.
2. Heat up until the water is cold.
3. Repeat steps 1 and 2 three more times.
4. Put a lollipop in your cauldron.
5. Heat up until the water is hot.

After you obtained the boots, you need to make sure you equip them.

Comment: does it matter if the crown is enchanted?

Comment: Yes it does. If you don't have an enchanted crown, you can go back to the cave and beat the Octopus King again.

Comment: when i do have the boots can I not move?

Comment: You need to make sure you equipped them.

Comment: @ElectricOrange79: You can move with the boots on by jumping